# Django Create post and send mail

Tags: django, email

after saving my variables in views.py that I have forwarded, can I send them as mail while saving the same fields? My mail sending codes are below but I didn't know how to do it.

```
def gcreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        gmember = gunluk(
            adsoyad=request.POST['adsoyad'],
            adsoyad2=request.POST['adsoyad2'],
            vardiya=request.POST['vardiya'],
            aciklama=request.POST['aciklama'],
            incident=request.POST['incident'],
            alinanaksiyon=request.POST['alinanaksiyon'],
            ulasilmayanekip=request.POST['ulasilmayanekip'],
            ulasilmayanbilgisi=request.POST['ulasilmayanbilgisi'],)
        try:
            gmember.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            pass
        send_mail(
        'test',
        'testmessage',
        'xx@xx.com',  
        ['xx@xx.com'],
        fail_silently=False
    )
        gmember.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ekleme İşlemi Başarılı!')
        return redirect('/gunlukistakibi')
    else:
        return render(request, 'gcreate.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Gmail less secure apps settings? Turn on 'less secure app access'.

Comment: this answer is more suited as a comment. It needs more explanation (and code)

Comment: i solved this problem with this codes; send_mail(
        gmember.adsoyad + "-" + gmember.adsoyad2,
         "Vardiya:" + gmember.vardiya + "\nAçıklama:" + gmember.aciklama + "\nIncident:" + gmember.incident + "\nAlınan Aksiyon:" + gmember.alinanaksiyon + "\nUlaşılamayan Ekip:" + gmember.ulasilmayanekip + "\nUlaşılmayan Bilgisi:" + gmember.ulasilmayanbilgisi,
        'xx@xx.com',  
        ['xx@xx.com'],
        fail_silently=False
    )

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def gcreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        gmember = gunluk(
            adsoyad=request.POST['adsoyad'],
            adsoyad2=request.POST['adsoyad2'],
            vardiya=request.POST['vardiya'],
            aciklama=request.POST['aciklama'],
            incident=request.POST['incident'],
            alinanaksiyon=request.POST['alinanaksiyon'],
            ulasilmayanekip=request.POST['ulasilmayanekip'],
            ulasilmayanbilgisi=request.POST['ulasilmayanbilgisi'],)
        try:
            gmember.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            pass
        send_mail(
    'Subject',
    'Message.',
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    ['to@example.com'],
)
        gmember.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ekleme İşlemi Başarılı!')
        return redirect('/gunlukistakibi')
    else:
        return render(request, 'gcreate.html')
```

In `settings.py` put the following

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' # else your smtp provider and Less Secure App should be allowed
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email address'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your email address password'
```